# How to run corda enterprise

Tags: enterprise, corda

I just research about Corda enterprise, I have downloaded file Corda enterprise3.zip when I extract this file, in this has a lot of files jar. Who can help me explaining how to run corda enterprise and use it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAR files are the Corda Enterprise dependencies for your node.

If you want to develop CorDapps against Corda Enterprise, you need to set your project's `build.gradle` file to depend on these dependencies. Do one of the following:

**Option 1:**

Place the Corda Enterprise binaries in your local Maven repository ( `~/.m2/repository` on osX, `C:\Documents and Settings\{your-username}\.m2]` on Windows) and add `mavenLocal()` to your `build.gradle` file's `repositories` block.

**Option 2:**

Publish the Corda Enterprise binaries to a personal Maven repository and add the following block to your `build.gradle` file's `repositories` block:

```
maven {
    url 'https://repo.mycompany.com/maven2'
    credentials {
        username "<username>"
        password "<password>"
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

Place the Corda Enterprise binaries somewhere on your local filesystem and add the following block to your `build.gradle` file's `repositories` block:

```
maven {
    url 'file://D:/path/to/local/directory'
}
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)